# How to stop "distribution upgrade available" messages with KPackagetKit/Fedora

Tags: upgrade, kde, fedora-13

Is there any way to disable the "distribution upgrade available" messages in KPackageKit without disabling all update notices?

I'm using Fedora 13 at the moment, matching a server install, and don't want to upgrade the distro. I still want notices when security and other updates are available, since they will also be applied to the server. I just don't want to be constantly bugged about the package upgrade.

Comment: Why not upgrade the distro and server?

Comment: I play no role in server administration, it's up to another team entirely. I just need to make sure my dev machine is kept basically in line with the servers.

Comment: You might as well just disable updates altogether.  [Fedora 13 is no longer receiving any.](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/announce/2011-June/002979.html)

Comment: @patches, yeah, that makes it simple enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Software Update Preferences tool and set "Check for major upgrades" to "Never".